# Ws invoked without autentication

Tags: spring-security

i have a problem with spring-security configuration..
I'm working with spring 3.2.3 release, and i have the following spring-security.xml:

```
<http pattern="/login*" security="none"/>
<http auto-config="true">

  <intercept-url  method="GET" pattern='/**' access='ROLE_ADMIN' />

  <form-login login-page="/login.ctx" default-target-url="/private/home.ctx" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailure.ctx" />
  <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout.ctx" />
</http>
```

The login autenticathe work fine, but if i call a service without authentication, the security allow to retrieve data, is not what I expected!

Example:

1 - Run the application on Jboss

2 - invoke this url:    `http://localhost:8080/ContextPanel/application/1` (this call a web services)

The url at point 2, invoke a service and return the required data, but the autentication at the application is not be performed!!

I would avoid this behavior!!

This is a snippet of web.xml:

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you show your `web.xml`? Specifically the part where spring security filter chain is mapped?

Comment: I am do not see the cause of the problem. Make sure that Spring Security works during mentioned WS call (turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.security` package and check logs). And normally `method="GET"` precision do not makes any sense, remove it if you can.

Comment: I had tried before, I added later: method = "GET" to see if something changed, but during the service call, seems not to be intercepted the spring security

Comment: can you share debug logs please